# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch in google OAuth-AngularJS Full-Stack generator

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) from AngularJS Full-Stack generator.While i am trying to use provider OAuth i am getting following error.After registering app in [console.google](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

i have downloaded json to be clear.

```
{
    "web" : {
        "auth_uri" : "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "client_secret" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "token_uri" : "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "client_email" : "362440374440-eof1u5bltnhqt1sjhgn92ohjugucsk74@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "redirect_uris" : ["http://localhost:9000"],
        "client_x509_cert_url" : "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/362440374440-eof1u5bltnhqt1sjhgn92ohjugucsk74@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id" : "36244037444xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxk74.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" : "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "javascript_origins" : ["http://localhost:9000"]
    }
}
```

It seems to me both redirects and origin are the same path.However i am getting all the time this error. I have removed several times app and create new app. I did several times reset secret. I have reset setting on google completely. After all again i am getting this error. Notice that i did the same configuration for facebook OAuth and i didn't get any problem at all. This is corresponding to following [issue](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/942#issuecomment-95194578)  where is not solved yet.

This is a error came from my browser:

```
    400. That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Request Details
from_login=1
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback
as=2d1026e8176fad07
client_id=362440374440-eof1u5bltnhqt1sjhgn92ohjugucsk74.apps.googleusercontent.com
hl=en
```

This is what i am getting in server side:

```
GET /login 304 9ms
GET /login 304 10ms
GET /auth/google 302 10ms - 0b
GET /login 304 1ms
GET /auth/google 302 0ms - 0b
```

Comment: You want your redirect_uri to be `http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback` first of all

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk No, i don't want, and if you see in json redirect is `http://localhost:9000` , i don't know why in my browser shows another redirect_uri

Comment: Your dev console should look something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/HnTgAdG.png). I have one set of credentials for my website, and one for when I develop locally.

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk so port in fullstack is 9000, doesn't mean that i should use 9000 for my link. As i see in your screenshot you have used 9050. Moreover i have applied the same configuration for twitter and fb which i got answer. Why it was not working with google?

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to 9050 for my own project, just ignore that. If you have the proper settings in the dev console, try changing the `google.callbackURL` in `server/config/environment/index.js` to this: `callbackURL: (process.env.DOMAIN || '') + '/auth/google/callback'`. The parentheses help it use the proper callback url locally.

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk thank you i got answer finally ;)

Comment: :D You're welcome. If you have any more questions, feel free to contact me on Gitter.im: https://gitter.im/Awk34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my answers in the comments above worked out. Making sure your callback URL in the Google Developers Console is `http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback`, and changing `google.callbackURL` in `server/config/environment/index.js` to  `(process.env.DOMAIN || '') + '/auth/google/callback'` fixed it.